Line intersecting simplex
Let $\Delta^d \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a $d$-simplex. Show that for every direction $\xi$ there exists a unique (!) line $l(\xi)$ such parallel to $\xi$ that intersects $\Delta^d$ in exactly two disjoint faces and this line depends continuously on $\xi$.
I was reading a topology book and this simple proposition came to my mind. I do not have ideas how to prove this

What have you tried? What is the definition of objects of interest? How would you start with ?
